# Align the list of page numbers, center on the right side, below the word Page, on ToC, LoT, LoF pages

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, memoir

I would like to align the list of page numbers, center on the right side, below word 'Page' on ToC, LoT and LoF for `memoir` class.

The following is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\addtocontents{toc}{\noindent\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}
\addtocontents{lot}{\noindent\bfseries Tables\hspace{7mm}Title~\hfill~Page\par}
\addtocontents{lof}{\noindent\bfseries Figures\hspace{7mm}Title~\hfill~Page\par}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures

\Blinddocument
\begin{table}[]\caption{My Table}\end{table}

\begin{figure}\caption{My Figure}\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below I update `\cft<unit>formatpnum` for each of the components, setting the width of the page number to be exactly that of **Page**:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\addtocontents{toc}{\noindent\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}
\addtocontents{lot}{\noindent\bfseries Tables\hspace{7mm}Title~\hfill~Page\par}
\addtocontents{lof}{\noindent\bfseries Figures\hspace{7mm}Title~\hfill~Page\par}

\newlength{\pnumwidthlen}
\settowidth{\pnumwidthlen}{\textbf{Page}}
\setpnumwidth{\the\pnumwidthlen}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterformatpnum}[1]{\makebox[\pnumwidthlen]{\bfseries#1}}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionformatpnum}[1]{\makebox[\pnumwidthlen]{\mdseries #1}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsectionformatpnum}[1]{\makebox[\pnumwidthlen]{\mdseries #1}}
\renewcommand{\cftfigureformatpnum}[1]{\makebox[\pnumwidthlen]{\mdseries #1}}
\renewcommand{\cfttableformatpnum}[1]{\makebox[\pnumwidthlen]{\mdseries #1}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures

\Blinddocument
\begin{table}\caption{My Table}\end{table}

\begin{figure}\caption{My Figure}\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works. Thanks.